# How to create new colors for Outlook calendar?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

We are facing an issue where we need to create Outlook addin which will add new colors for outlook calendars. As for now outlook only has 9 colors to choose from when trying to change calendars colors. In our case 9 is not enough and we need to find a way to add more colors there. How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the colors for Calendar Overlays are not customizable; we are stuck with the nine colors.